# Swapping with NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller, multiple-views

I am trying swapping two Views in a Windows. I am using Cocoa Framework (just for Mac) with Xcode 5.1.1 and NSViewController for get it. All compile perfectly but this doesn't works, 
I get the next message from compiler:

> "libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff866995fd start + 1"

[This is my Xcode Project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/l76botn1633d39t/SwappingViews.zip)

.h file

```
#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"
#import "PrimaryViewController.h" //My views
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface
AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myCustomView;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSViewController *myViewController;

-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

//@synthesize myCustomView = _myCustomView;<br/>
//@synthesize myViewController = _myViewController;<br/>

-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked on the first button");
    [[_myViewController view ]removeFromSuperview];
    _myViewController = [[PrimaryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrimaryView­Controller" bundle:nil];
    [_myCustomView addSubview:[_myViewController view]];
    [[_myViewController view] setFrame:[_myCustomView bounds]];
}

-(IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Clicked on the second button");
    [[_myViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
    _myViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondaryView­Controller" bundle:nil];
    [_myCustomView addSubview:[_myViewController view]];
    [[_myViewController view]setFrame:[_myCustomView bounds]];
}

@end
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Message from the compiler? Are you sure it's not a crash?  If so post the stack trace.

Comment: @mohacs thank for ask, i've fixed it, and i have could not saving it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In `SecondaryViewController.xib` you named the file owner as `SecondViewController`. Change it to `SecondaryViewController` and it should work.

Comment: I am trying to make the same tutorial workng, but I am unable to do so.  I also downloaded the project from the link above, but it crashes, same as the app that I did. Crash message is the following: -[NSNib initWithNibNamed:bundle:] could not load the nibName: NSViewController in bundle NSBundle.....Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

O yeah, when i created my second "view" i created a file: `SecondViewController.xib`, SecondViewController.h, and SecondViewController.m

So when i created a instance of it, into the method "button2Clicked" in the, `initWithNibName`

I called it @"SecondaryViewController" (vs @"SecondViewController").

I removed `SecondaryViewController` and i changed it, for `SecondViewController` and all works perfectly, thanks @TheAmateurProgrammerless ;)

> [Here my project fix it](https://www.mediafire.com/?tfwi1qbdjzy8lof)